# adding a font awesome button to the document

Tags: javascript

I want to add a font-awesome symbol to a button and then append the button to my page. My code so far:

```
var rem=document.createElement("button");
rem.setAttribute('value','<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
document.appendChild(rem);
```

But it does not work. There's this error on the console:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

So how do i achieve this? I am ok with using other code such as jQuery, etc

Comment: please provide entire code

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe that is the code i have within my <script> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things...

The first is how you're attempting to add the icon to the button. By using `rem.set('value', '...')` you're basically saying the output should be

`<button value="<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>"></button>`

...but what you really want is...

`<button><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`

To achieve this use `rem.innerHTML = '...'`

And secondly, you're trying to append to the document which is not valid which is why you're getting the error "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.".

What you want is to append it to the `<body>` or another element on page, you can do this with `document.body.appendChild(rem)`. See below for resolved code.

```js
var rem = document.createElement('button');
    rem.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
document.body.appendChild(rem);
```

And if you're already using jQuery you can do the following...

```js
var rem = $( '<button><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' );
$('body').append(rem);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here. Firstly the cause of the error is because you cannot append a `button` element to the `document`. You need to append it to an element within the `body`. In the example below I used the `body` itself, but any will work.

Secondly you need to set the `<i>` element containing the icon as a *child* of the `button` you create, not the `value` attribute.

```js
var rem = document.createElement("button");
rem.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
document.body.appendChild(rem);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```